# Create new random sentence with each click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've successfully made a random sentence generator based on the values of an object in an array that works based on a click of a button. What I can't figure out is how to create a new sentence with each click of the button. 
It seems like I could just clear out the contents of #output when the button is clicked and randomWord() would just run again but no dice.

```
  var words = {
    noun : ['mouse','bird','cat','dog'],
    verb : ['runs','sleeps','explodes','flies'],
    place : ['house', 'space station', 'car', 'office']
  };

var container = document.getElementById('output');
  function print(sentence){
  container.innerHTML = sentence;
}

var noun;
var verb;
var place;

var word;
var sentence;
var button;

function randomWord( type ){
  rando = Math.floor(Math.random() * words[type].length);
  word = words[type][rando];
  return word;
}

noun = randomWord('noun');
verb = randomWord('verb');
place = randomWord('place');

$('button').click(function(){
   $('#output ').empty();
   var sentence = "<p>The " + noun + " " + verb + " in the " + place + ".</p>";
  print(sentence);
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/lowbelly/pen/VaEvMM)

Comment: Move the 3 lines above your button method inside your click funciton.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your randomised variables each time you click the button, currently you're doing it once during script initialisation:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#output ').empty();

    //generate new random words on click
    noun = randomWord('noun');
    verb = randomWord('verb');
    place = randomWord('place');

    var sentence = "<p>The " + noun + " " + verb + " in the " + place + ".</p>";
    print(sentence);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- id reference to output has an extra space

  $('#output ').empty() ===> $('#output').empty();
- You may want to use Document Ready from jQuery
- And like the other answers stated, you need the random calls in the clickable action

Quick test here:

```
<html>

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" ></script>
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {


var words = {
   noun : ['mouse','bird','cat','dog'],
   verb : ['runs','sleeps','explodes','flies'],
   place : ['house', 'space station', 'car', 'office']
};

var container = document.getElementById('output');

function print(sentence){
  container.innerHTML = sentence;
}

var noun;
var verb;
var place;

var word;
var sentence;
var button;

function randomWord( type ){
   rando = Math.floor(Math.random() * words[type].length);
   word = words[type][rando];
   return word;
}

$('#button').click(function(){

   noun = randomWord('noun');
   verb = randomWord('verb');
   place = randomWord('place');

   $('#output').empty();
   var sentence = "<p>The " + noun + " " + verb + " in the " + place + ".  </p>";
   print(sentence);
 });

 });
 </script>
 <div id="output"></div>

 <button id="button">click</button>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just have to try:

```
   $('button').click(function(){
       noun = randomWord('noun');
       verb = randomWord('verb');
       place = randomWord('place');

       var sentence = "<p>The " + noun + " " + verb + " in the " + place + ".</p>";
       print(sentence);
   });
```